# config file transformation on setup installation

Tags: c#, .net

I want to transform app.config to the path that users selects while installing the setup of the project. i know how to write the transformation through the xdt syntax but those transformations take place when the setup is build. i want similar transforms to work when installing the setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own C# code to do the transformation in the installer class and copy the required file to the path.